# NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.user_id

Tags: python, django

I am using django-allauth for user registration and login but I have just one more step called "click to finish" this should appear to complete their profile when user registers. But i am getting following error.
first of all, here I have tried so far

**model.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

def __str__(self):
    return self.email


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('users.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

**forms.py**

```
 class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')

  class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')



  class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
     company_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
     phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
     city = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
     address = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['company_name', 'phone_number', 'city', 'address']
```

**views.py**

```
def profile(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        redirect('dashboard')
else:
    form = ProfileForm()
return render(request, 'users/profile.html', {'form':form})
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\Zako5\.virtualenvs\inventory_project-V0PloAkR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Zako5\.virtualenvs\inventory_project-V0PloAkR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Zako5\.virtualenvs\inventory_project-V0PloAkR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Zako5\inventory_project\users\views.py", line 13, in profile
    form.save()
  File "C:\Users\Zako5\.virtualenvs\inventory_project-V0PloAkR\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 458, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "C:\Users\Zako5\.virtualenvs\inventory_project-V0PloAkR\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Zako5\.virtualenvs\inventory_project-V0PloAkR\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Zako5\.virtualenvs\inventory_project-V0PloAkR\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.user_id
[06/Apr/2019 11:50:13] "POST /account/profile HTTP/1.1" 500 150456
```

I have searched some answers but none of them worked in my case.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you already using Abstract User, why you are using Profile in a One to One relationship? And coming to your error, you are not mentioning which user profile in your `profile` view. In your profile model you have user, company_name, phone_number, city, address. But you are saving only for last four.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the value of the `user` field in Profile object.

For that, before saving the profile, you can attach the user from `request.user`. Using `form.save(commit=False)` will return a Profile instance which has not been saved in Database, then add the user to that profile instance.

For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
     else:
        form = ProfileForm()
     return render(request, 'users/profile.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works very well. One thing can you tell me please? When user registers it should automatically redirect to profile form to fill in but it redirects to dashboard profile form is missing. how can i do this?

Comment: I think its better to use signals to create profiles. A profile will automatically created when a user is created through signals. You will find good example in this tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html